# Position coordinate values doubled in IOS UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, coordinates

I have a ViewController which contains a UINavigationBar and a UIScrollView.
Inside the scroll view I am placing other views to create a paging type thing.
I made this work perfectly but I had to work around a very weird thing where all my coordinate values inside the UIScrollView were doubled, yet elements returned their correct coordinates in .frame.origin.

Not knowing why this was and having searched and found nothing I assumed I must be wrong and performed a test.

I created the scenario above but in the background I placed a measured image of a 10x10 pixel grid.
I ran it with this in viewDidLoad for the viewController:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Size to fit the screen
float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
height -= [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
height -= self.navBar.frame.origin.y;
height -= self.navBar.frame.size.height;
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
frame.size.height = height;
self.scrollView.frame = frame;

frame.origin.y = 10;
testUIView *testView = [[testUIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:testView];
```

The result confirmed my darkest fears. 
The grid is revealed under the testView showing two blocks of ten pixels.
The values are indeed doubled - but why is this and what should I do about it?

[edit]

For the curious, here is the code for the view being inserted:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"testUIView" owner:self options:nil];

        self.view.frame = frame;

        [self addSubview:self.view];
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lesson here was "try to be observant," and also "don't leave details out."

x and y values were doubled because in initWithFrame the frame is applied directly to a subview which is an IBOutlet from an xib. adding the frame unmodified meant that the x and y values were retained within the coordinate space of the view. So the view appears at y=10 in the parent and the subview appears at y=10 in the view resulting in the layout placing the subview at y=20.

Solution: reset the frame origin before applying it to subviews.

It's pointy hat time!

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your code how you are determining that something is "doubled," but the reason is almost certainly that you are confusing points and pixels and you're running on a Retina device.

Almost all coordinates (particularly things in `CGPoint`) are given in points. On a Retina display, there are 4 pixels per point (two rows by two columns). This is called the `scale`, and is "2" for a Retina display. See [Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact this has run in the iPone emulator and the two retina (iPhone) emulators and always with the same result. Am running the test again just to be sure.

Comment: Confirmed the result is the same in both older and newer (retina) emulators. Additionally this effect only appears in the UIScrollView. I see your point that pixels and points are not the same thing. I am determining the doubling effect by visually measuring the resulting layout. I would post an image but it appears that I am too much the noob for such antics.

Comment: Anyway, this is my point. The input values should result in predictable layout behaviour. In this case they do not. The view placed at y=10 appears at y=20. This is visually the same distance as the height of the status bar, which is also 20. It makes it very difficult to place views inside this UIScrollView, though it can be done - by dividing all of the coordinates by 2.